# Formatting query parameters that are arrays in Ember.Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, query-string

Let's say that I have an Ember.Data query I'd like to make:

```
this.store.find('items', {itemIds: [1,2,3]});
```

By default, Ember.Data creates a URL that looks like this:

```
items?itemIds%5B%5D=1&itemIds%5B%5D=2&itemIds%5B%5D=3
```

But the REST api I am connecting to wants it in this format:

```
items?itemIds=1&itemIds=2&itemIds=3
```

How do I achieve this adaptation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the `RESTAdapter` and override the `ajax` method and create the URL that you want to use based on the circumstances.

```
App.ItemsAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajax: function(url, type, options){
    if(myCircumstance){
      var data = options.data;
      delete options.data;
      url = url + ......;
    }
    return this._super(url, type, options);
  }
});
```

REST Adapter implementation: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js

Comment: Are you sure? In https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/build-url-mixin.js#L60 id arrays are excluded and the comment says that this is because they are passed as query parms. This (and the code) indicates that query parms aren't really handled here.

Comment: You're right, it will have to hop up to the ajax level.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see looking on the ember data code, you'd have to overwrite the `RestAdapter`'s `findQuery` or `ajax` method, see http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findMany (see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js). Both are private, but the store expects the findQuery to be there (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.16.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store/finders.js#L137), so I wouldn't expect this behaviour to change soon.

If you use this for production, you'd better open a bug report to have this or something similar exposed as a public hook, as I cannot see one being there thus far.

Answer (score 0):

@Kingpin2k's answer is the right direction, but the solution is even simpler. To create the query params, Ember Data simply [yields](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.12.0/addon/adapters/rest.js#L1083) the data object, wrapped in the options object, to the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function.

Knowing that, we just need another query param serializer. By default, jQuery will serialize arrays the way TS described. You can change the way of serialization by overriding the [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method. But luckily we don't even have too, because the `$.param` function has a second argument called `traditional` serialization. If set to `true`, the serialization will be like TS wanted*.

The `jQuery.Ajax` function also has the `traditional` flag to use the traditional style of param serialization. Combining this facts, you just need to set this flag yourself:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajax(url, type, options) {
    if (options) {
      options.traditional = true;
    }
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

P.S. If you use the [JSONAPIAdapter](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html), the trick is the same, because the JSONAPIAdapter extends the RESTAdapter.

*If you need another serialization, you need to override the $.param.